# Doubt in the proof of Banach Alaoglu Theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

I'm reading a proof of **Banach Alaoglu** Theorem from Functional Analysis by S Keshavan on page 142:

**Theorem:** Let $V$ be a Banach space. Then $B^{*}$, the closed unit ball in $V^*$ is weak$^*$-compact.

**Proof:** For each $x$ in $V$, we let $U_{x}$ be the closed ball of radius $||x||_{b}$ in $\mathbb{C}$. Then, we can take $U = \Pi_{x\in V} U_{x}$,which is clearly compact by Tychonoff theorem.

The map
$$
\tau : f \mapsto (f(x))_{x\in V}
$$
defines a continuous injection from the unit ball of $B^*$ to $U$. Let $A$ denote the image of $\tau$, so it suffices to prove that $A$ is closed in $U$.

Let $(f_x)_{x\in V} \in cl(\tau(B^*))$. Define for $x\in V$, $f(x)=f_x$. The proof will be complete if we can show that $f$ is linear.

let $\epsilon >0$ be given. Then given $x$ and $y$ in $V$,

we can find $g \in B^{*}$ such that $ \vert g(x)-f(x) \vert < \epsilon/3$,$ \vert g(y)-f(y) \vert < \epsilon/3$,$ \vert g(x+y)-f(x+y) \vert < \epsilon/3$

> Can someone explain me how do we get $g$ mentioned in last paragraph?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that, by definition $\tau(B^*)$ is dense in $\def\c{\mathop{\rm cl}}\c(\tau B^*)$. Given now $x,y \in V$ and $\epsilon > 0$, the set 
$$ W := \{h \in \c(\tau B^*) : |h(x) - f(x)|, |h(y) - f(y)|, |h(x+y) - f(x+y)| < \epsilon/3 \} $$
is an open - by the definition of the product topology - set containing $f$. As $f \in \c(\tau B^*)$, there is an $g \in B^*$ such that $\tau(g) \in  W$.

Comment: Ah,I see.Thanks a lot.Regards,